# Integers solutions of products of truncated Riemann zeta functions

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations, computational-number-theory

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ be a positive integer.

It is possible to prove that the equation $F_1(n)=m$ where $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ and
$$
F_1(n)=(1+2+\ldots+n)\cdot\left(\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\dots+\frac{1}{n}\right)
$$
is solvable only for $n=3$ and $m=11$.
I've tried to generalize the result for the function
$$
F_k(n)=\big(1^k+2^k+\ldots+n^k\big)\cdot\left(\frac{1}{1^k}+\frac{1}{2^k}+\dots+\frac{1}{n^k}\right)
$$ where $k \geq 2$, i.e. asking for which $n$ the expression $F_k(n)$ is an integer, but I'm not succeeding.
Does some of you know if this equation is solvable in general or for some particular values of $k$, for example for $k=2$?

I've tried with the basic elementary number theory techniques.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should be noted that $n=m=1$ is also a solution.

Comment: for $k=2$ one needs that $n(n+1)(2n+1)/6$ cancels out all $1/p^2$ for $n/2 <p \le n$ prime, so in particular $n^2/4 \le p^2 \le 2n+1$ for at least one such $p$ by Bertrand since $p$ can divide only one of the three factors, or $n \le 8$ etc; similar arguments work for higher $k$ given that we know that $1^k+2^k+\ldots+n^k$ is a polynomial of degree $k+1$ in $n$

Comment: $F_1(n)=\frac{n\ (n+1)}{2} H_n$ and $F_k(n)=H_n^{(-k)}\ H_n^{(k)}$ where $H_n$ is the harmonic number and $H_n^{(k)}$ is the harmonic number of order $k$.